# TypeError: deployer.getBalance is not a function

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat-deploy

I want to know the balance in the account but am facing the error that getBalance is not a function.

**Deploy.js**

```
const main = async () => {
const [deployer] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
const accountBalance = await deployer.getBalance();

console.log("Deploying contracts with account: ", deployer.getAddress());
console.log("Account balance: ", accountBalance.toString());

const waveContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("WavePortal");
const waveContract = await waveContractFactory.deploy();
await waveContract.waitForDeployment();

console.log("WavePortal address: ", waveContract.address);
};
  
const runMain = async () => {
try {
    await main();
    process.exit(0);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
}
};

runMain();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that this method exists then Check the version for Ethers library or HRE and check the docs for some changes in method calls and allocations

try to find and match your versions on docs and installation environment as well

most probably that is going to fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be using ethers version 6.x.x. If thats the case you can no longer use getBalance directly with signer. getBalance is now a function of provider. This worked for me.

```
const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
const accountBalance = await deployer.provider.getBalance(deployer.address));
```